# A way to replace strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I am looking for the best way to replace strings in javascript. Only problem, I need it replaced like this:

Here's my string: `The brown fox jumps over the brown fence`

I need javascript to find two words like this: `The **brown** fox jumps over the **brown** fence`

And I need to replace the string with what is in the middle of those words: `fox jumps over the`

I've been looking online but I cant find anything.

Any idea?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace ?!

Comment: The problem statement isn't very clear. Are you trying to find repeated occurrences of any word, and then return what's between them? Why are you picking "brown" in particular?

Comment: What is the expected output string (after replacing something by something else)?

Comment: I am trying to find words in a string and just get whats in between, brown is just an example.

Comment: Please make a good attempt to *search* first (and *be diligent* about it). I recommend "javascript replace string between words". You will end up finding out how to do this, which can be trivially solved with a regular expression.

Answer (score 3):

This will do the job

```
var str = "The brown fox jumps over the brown fence";
var newStr = str.replace(/brown(.+)brown/g,"\"help me without i have to tell anything\"");
```

The result will be:

> The "help me without i have to tell anything" fence

a variant is this

```
var newStr.replace(/brown(.+)brown/g,"brown dog sleep over the brown");
```

resulting in:

> The brown dog sleep over the brown fence